# Vue - how can i add a button to each row in a Vuetify datatable?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm new to Vue and i'm dealing with datatables. I'm using Vuetify's datatables to create a component that, on page load, sends a request to my backend, receives some data and shows that data on a datatable.

This is my current code:

```
<template>
  <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="balances"
    :items-per-page="5"
    class="elevation-1"
  ></v-data-table>
</template>

<script>


export default {
 
  data() {
    return {

      search: '',

      headers: [
        { text: 'Asset', value: 'symbol' },
        { text: 'Amount', value: 'amount' },
      ],

        balances: [],
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.fetchData()
  },
  methods: {
    fetchData() {
      fetch('MYURL')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          this.balances = data;
        })
    }
  }
}

</script>
```

The problem i'm facing now is adding a button to each row in the table, and this button should send a request to my backend with that row's data, so i need to add a button that, when clicked, can fetch the row's data. Is there any way to do that? I tried looking into Vuetify's docs but i didn't found much about a task like this one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [add icons in actions columns and in each row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65368087/add-icons-in-actions-columns-and-in-each-row)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a new column, set value to `action` for example, and add a `slot` in the table as follows:

```js
new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      search: '',
      headers: [
        { text: 'Asset', value: 'symbol' },
        { text: 'Amount', value: 'amount' },
        { text: 'Send', value: 'action' }
      ],
      balances: [
        { symbol: "$", amount: 100 },
        { symbol: "$", amount: 200 },
      ],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    sendRequest(rowData) {
      console.log(rowData)
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<v-app id="app">
  <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="balances"
    :items-per-page="5"
    class="elevation-1"
  >
    <template v-slot:item.action="{ item }">
      <v-btn @click="sendRequest(item)">
        Send
      </v-btn>
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
</v-app>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer! I'm getting the following error: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined. I think this might be actual table i have is inside of a component, so everything needs to be wrapped by a <template> tag

Comment: @JayK23 you are welcome, please mark the answer as the solution if you're satisfied with it. Yes, keep the component wrapped in a ``template`` in your case, I just removed it to show a quick example. Feel free to share a more detailed fiddle if you face more issues

Comment: You can only take the part of the new object in ``headers`` and the ``slot`` inside the table

Comment: Alright, sorry for my confusing answer, basically since i'm new to Vue, i was afraid that using two times <template> was going to create problems, but it didn't! This is the perfect solution, just beautiful! Thank you a lot!